# wordpress keeps stripping code for for no reason

Tags: wordpress

For the love of god can someone please tell me  why this code keeps getting stripped in WP page editor. I cant switch to visual at all. I have to stay in HTML at all times. if i don't, WordPress keeps removing the code. What is going on?

```
</div>
<div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-4" style="width: 68%"> 
 <div style="font-size:0">
  <div id="bc9d86d7ebcb478ea75fec22a82fc804" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; z-index: 0; margin: 0px; border-width: 0px; " class="art-collage"> 
   <div class="art-slider art-slidecontainerbc9d86d7ebcb478ea75fec22a82fc804"> 
    <div class="art-slider-inner"> 
     <div class="art-slide-item art-slidebc9d86d7ebcb478ea75fec22a82fc8040"></div>
     <div class="art-slide-item art-slidebc9d86d7ebcb478ea75fec22a82fc8041"></div>
     <div class="art-slide-item art-slidebc9d86d7ebcb478ea75fec22a82fc8042"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="art-slidenavigator art-slidenavigatorbc9d86d7ebcb478ea75fec22a82fc804">
    <a href="#" class="art-slidenavigatoritem"></a>
    <a href="#" class="art-slidenavigatoritem"></a>
    <a href="#" class="art-slidenavigatoritem"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what code are you referring to?

Comment: </div><div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-4" style="width: 68%" >
        <div style="font-size:0"><div id="bc9d86d7ebcb478ea75fec22a82fc804" style="position: relative; display: 

inline-block; z-index: 0; margin: 0px;  border-width: 0px;  " class="art-collage">
<div class="art-slider art-slidecontainerbc9d86d7ebcb478ea75fec22a82fc804">
    <div class="art-slider-inner">
<div class="art-slide-item art-slidebc9d86d7ebcb478ea75fec22a82fc8040">

Comment: </div>
<div class="art-slide-item art-slidebc9d86d7ebcb478ea75fec22a82fc8041">

</div>
<div class="art-slide-item art-slidebc9d86d7ebcb478ea75fec22a82fc8042">

</div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="art-slidenavigator art-slidenavigatorbc9d86d7ebcb478ea75fec22a82fc804">
<a href="#" class="art-slidenavigatoritem"></a><a href="#" class="art-slidenavigatoritem"></a><a href="#" 

class="art-slidenavigatoritem"></a>
</div>



    </div>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: sorry about that. for some reason i was unable to enter the code so i entered it above in two parts. thanks

Comment: @user1993107, you are free to [edit] your Question whenever needed.

Answer (score 1):

This article explains how to fix common issues with the way Wordpress handles HTML in its editor:

http://smartypants.com/blogs/index.php/2012/08/06/a-fix-for-html-issues-with-the-wordpress-visual-editor/

Essentially it explains to download this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-wpautop/

And to upgrade Wordpress' editor, TinyMCE, to an advanced version of itself via this "plugin":
http://www.laptoptips.ca/projects/tinymce-advanced/

Cheers